# Qt C++ фильтр для бд

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

необходимо сделать фильтр для бд. Есть поля в них нужно вписать значение, которое потом должно перейти в запрос и вывести результат в tableView. Сам вопрос заключается в том, как взять значение из comboBox, dateEdit и textEdit и поместить их в sql-запрос [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```
QString filter=QString("mycombo='%1' and mydate='%2' and mytext='%3'")
.arg(ui->comboBox->currentText())
.arg(ui->dateEdit->date().toString("dd.MM.yyyy"))
.arg(ui->lineEdit->text());
ui->tableView->setFilter(filter);
```

Comment: у меня ругается на setfilter (no member name setfilter in tableview)

Comment: @АртёмПфеффер вероятно имелся ввиду метод setFilter() класса QSqlTableModel. Что аналогично SQL запросу с условием WHERE и данными из строки filter.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения за неточность. setFilter это конечно же метод модели а не самого виджета таблицы